# ¿Es posible crear un constructor genérico para diferentes Objectos con diferentes atributos?

Tags: java

```
package ecommerce.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import ecommerce.model.Category;
import ecommerce.model.Product;

@XmlRootElement
@Data
public class CategoryDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int categoryId;

    private String description;

    private byte disabled;

    private int displayOrder;

    private String name;

    private List<Product> products;

    public CategoryDTO() {

    }

    public CategoryDTO(Category category) {
        if(category != null) {
            this.categoryId = category.getCategoryId();
            this.description = category.getDescription();
            this.disabled = category.getDisabled();
            this.displayOrder = category.getDisplayOrder();
            this.name = category.getName();
            this.products = category.getProducts();
        }
    }

    public Category toEntity() {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        category.setDescription(description);
        category.setDisabled(disabled);
        category.setDisplayOrder(displayOrder);
        category.setName(name);
        category.setProducts(products);
        return category;
    }

    public CategoryDTO toEntityDTO() {
        CategoryDTO category = new CategoryDTO();
        category.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        category.setDescription(description);
        category.setDisabled(disabled);
        category.setDisplayOrder(displayOrder);
        category.setName(name);
        category.setProducts(products);
        return category;
    }
}
```

Tengo mi capa de Data Transaction Object, donde a cada clase anémica le asigno un constructor, en este caso

```
public CategoryDTO(Category category)
```

y los métodos

```
public Category toEntity()
public CategoryDTO toEntityDTO()
```

Quisiera hacer de ellos una clase genérica para así poder extenderlas en todas mis demás clases anémicas. Se les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Se pueden llegar a conseguir cosas bastante optimizadas si se combinan interfaces, funciones abstractas y clases aplantilladas. Puedes empezar, investigando sobre ello. Tal vez pueda ponerte un ejemplo durante el fin de semana.